# Wordpress doesn't see my custom theme

Tags: wordpress

I created my own WP Theme with following folders and files

[image]

**style.css** is placed in css folder, with comment at the beginning of the file

```
/*   
* Theme Name: Test
 * Description: Test theme
 * Author: Test
 * Version: 1.0
*/
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_css' );

function enqueue_theme_css()
{
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css'
    );
}
```

But WP doesn't see my theme

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you using purchased theme?

Comment: No, I made it by myself.

Comment: Are you trying to install the child theme?

Comment: No, it's not a child theme, it's a standalone theme.

Comment: it seems its style.css path problem, it has to be in root of theme

Answer (score 1):

@Heidel: 
Put style.css into theme folder outside css folder, remove from css folder and then check it out.Then it will work and start displaying into admin section.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The style.css was missing: template: theme in the commented header i.e.

```html
/*
 Theme Name:   testTheme
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Test Child Theme
 Author:       Test
 Author URI:   http://exmple.com
 Template:     test
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  test-child
*/
```